# How do I suppress tensorflow from showing the detection score for each class to make my bounding box prediction readable

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have trained the a tensorflow model using the Tensorflow Object Detection API to detect numbers in text. However, I am unable to see the boxes surrounding the digits as the detection scores and the class which are being printed on the image are making it indecipherable. My current output for an image is something like this [predicted_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lir29.png)

Can anyone please help me to get a clear bounding box around an image so that I can see whether the model has trained properly.

I have tried changing the font and the line thickness in the `visualizations_util` file in the `object_detection/utils` but it isn't working

Comment: Could you give a link for the notebook on GitHub or some platform so that we could try the code?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out. I had to go to the `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` function in the file `visulaizations_utils.py` file and set the value of `skip_scores` to `False`